# Difference between `ls --color` and `ls --color /` command

Tags: command-line

When I type `ls --color` command. I get the usual directory in which I am working. But on typing the `ls --color /` command, I get different directory.
[Commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxnMB.jpg)

Answer (score 8):

This is obvious.

`ls --color` shows the contents of your current directory.

`ls --color /` shows the contents of `/` directory.

`/` directory is the root directory of your system.